# HTML Agility Pack - retrieving multiple values from TD & TR tags

Tags: html, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I am new to HTML agility pack, there are some values on a web page I need to get but couldn't findout how to. Hope you can help me.

Best regards.

**Sample HTML portion:**

```
...
<div id="page-bgtop">
    <div id="page-bgbtm">
    <div id="content">
    <div class="post">
    <div class="entry">
    <center>
    <div/>
    <div>
    <table class="CSSTableGenerator" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" id="GridView2" style="width: 98%; border-collapse: collapse;">
    <tbody>
    <tr style="font-weight: bold;">
    <tr style="background-color: rgb(239, 243, 251);">
    <td>
    <a href="Super-Loto-Cekilis-Sonucu.aspx?ID=506.Hafta-29/06/2017-Super-Loto-Sonucu">506</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="Super-Loto-Cekilis-Sonucu.aspx?ID=506.Hafta-29/06/2017-Super-Loto-Sonucu">29/06/2017</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="Super-Loto-Cekilis-Sonucu.aspx?ID=506.Hafta-29/06/2017-Super-Loto-Sonucu">4</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="Super-Loto-Cekilis-Sonucu.aspx?ID=506.Hafta-29/06/2017-Super-Loto-Sonucu">20</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="Super-Loto-Cekilis-Sonucu.aspx?ID=506.Hafta-29/06/2017-Super-Loto-Sonucu">21</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="Super-Loto-Cekilis-Sonucu.aspx?ID=506.Hafta-29/06/2017-Super-Loto-Sonucu">32</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="Super-Loto-Cekilis-Sonucu.aspx?ID=506.Hafta-29/06/2017-Super-Loto-Sonucu">43</a>
    </td>
    <td>
    <a href="Super-Loto-Cekilis-Sonucu.aspx?ID=506.Hafta-29/06/2017-Super-Loto-Sonucu">47</a>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="background-color: white;">
    <td>
...
```

**Values I would like to get:**
506
29/06/2017
4
20
21
32
43
47

PS: This is just a sample html portion, there are many rows of value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the XPath [descendant-or-self axis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes/descendant-or-self) (`//`), specifically `//tr` to select the all table rows, then check the row(s) for hyperlinks in each cell:

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html);
//               ^^^^^^ your HTML snippet above
var rows = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr");

if (rows != null && rows.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var row in rows)
    {
        var links = row.SelectNodes("./td/a");
        if (links != null) Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", links.Select(x => x.InnerText)));

    }
}
```

Output:

> 506 29/06/2017 4 20 21 32 43 47

Comment: One more thing, how to insert those values to a table which has exact same columns. (drawNo, drawDate, ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4, ball5, ball6)